# How to plan the Timescaledb for huge price data with simple table column

Tags: python, mongodb, influxdb, timescaledb

I am trying out the timescaledb to store price data. The price table schema is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE prices(
  time TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
  pid  VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
  price DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL
)
```

We need to keep the price data for most 183 days. The current database we use for the price data is mongodb. We have already 9 billion records in mongodb that is really slow to insert and remove records over 183 days.

The query is pretty simple. Given the `pid` and the date range, for example, 7das, the query returns a tuple containing the average price, max price and min price. The RPS for query is around 20.

Plus, we daily curate around 30 million price records that will be inserted into mongodb daily in the early morning around 2 AM. It takes at least 4 hours to complete the insertion.

Looking and testing out timescaledb for such a use case, I, of course, enabled hyepertable and set interval chunk for 24 hours and also create an index on `pid`. This is what I have been done for far to complete the insertion of 30 million records within 20 minutes with python `psycopg2.copy_from`. Would like to know what other caveats or suggestions for the case I am encountering in terms of planning out timescaledb in an optimal way?

p.s. I did try influxdb but it didn't really perform well when series cardinality is over a million or so.

Comment: Try also inserting data to VictoriaMetrics. It should use lower amount of resources comparing to InfluxDB on high-cardinality data - see https://medium.com/@valyala/insert-benchmarks-with-inch-influxdb-vs-victoriametrics-e31a41ae2893

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Timescale co-founder)

A few suggestions:

1. Make your composite index on `pid, timestamp desc`, not just pid.

https://blog.timescale.com/blog/use-composite-indexes-to-speed-up-time-series-queries-sql-8ca2df6b3aaa/

2. See if creating a continuous aggregate would help your use case.  For example, something like:

- *CREATE VIEW prices_daily WITH (timescaledb.continuous) AS SELECT pid, time_bucket('1 day', time) AS bucket, min(prices) as min_price, max(price) as max_price FROM prices GROUP BY pid, bucket;*

https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/continuous-aggregates

3. Explore the use of compression to both reduce storage and enable faster scans over long time-periods.  In particular, given that your queries are usually by pid, I would probably use something like:

- *ALTER TABLE prices
  SET (timescaledb.compress,
  timescaledb.compress_segmentby = 'pid');*

https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/compression

Also, welcome you to join the TimescaleDB community on slack for these types of questions:  https://slack.timescale.com/

Comment: Hi Mike! definitely will check out the blog and docs for the advanced tweaking. Btw, joining the Slack :)

Comment: @taitung.bujn for deleting older data I suggest to look to drop_chunks and the policy https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#add_drop_chunks_policy

Comment: thanks, k_rus, removing old is one I also need to take care for the data retention policy.